# Transactions With Mongoose and NodeJs, calling an external function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, transactions

I have some code that have implemented Transaction and it works perfectly, but now I need to call a function inside this code(it has a comment in my code example), both parts have to have success or then nothing have to be done. It is not working properly. How can I integrate the "sendCashback, function" to work perfectly with my Transaction?

This is my code:

```
var transaction: any 
  let cashback_sent: any
  try{
    const transactiontimectrl = Number(process.env.TRANSACTION_TIME_STOP)   
    let dt = new Date();
    dt.setSeconds(dt.getSeconds() - transactiontimectrl);
    const timectrl = dt.toISOString(); 

    console.log('teste transaction1')
    console.log(timectrl)

    const session = await mongoose.startSession();

    await session.withTransaction(async () => {
      const transactionRes = await Transaction.findOne(
        {
          from: from,
          //to: to,
          //value: valuetodebit,
          createdAt: {$gt: timectrl}
        }).session(session)
        
      
      if(!transactionRes){
        transaction = await Transaction.create([
          {
            from,
            to,
            value: value,
            division_factor: destinationUserGroup.division_factor,
            title: title || null,
            description: description || null,
            type: type || null,
            hasCashback: hasCashback,
            realmoney: realmoney,
            valuetodebit: valuetodebit
          }],{ session }) 
      }else{
        throw new Error('Erro, uma transação semelhante foi realizada recentemente')
      }

      if (!transaction) {
        throw new Error('Erro, tente novamente mais tarde') 
      }
    
      console.log('@sadihjaisvq3')

      let fromBalance
      //Saldo real
      if (realmoney) {
        fromBalance = await Balance.findOne({
          type: IBalanceType.GENERAL,
          user: from
        }).session(session)
      }
      //Saldo cashback
      else {
        fromBalance = await Balance.findOne({
          type: IBalanceType.CASHBACK,
          user: from
        }).session(session)
      }

      console.log('****criar balance2')

      let toBalance = await Balance.findOne({
        type: IBalanceType.GENERAL,
        user: to
      }).session(session)
      console.log('****criar balance1', toBalance)

      if (!toBalance) {
        console.log('****criar balance')
        toBalance = await Balance.create(
        {
          user: to
        })
      }

      
      let toLivetPay = await Balance.findOne({
        type: IBalanceType.GENERAL,
        user: toLivet
      }).session(session)

      if (!fromBalance || !toBalance || !toLivetPay) throw new Error()

      if (!credit) {
        fromBalance.value = fromBalance.value + parseFloat(valuetodebit) * -1
      }
      // fromBalance.value = fromBalance.value + parseFloat(valuetodebit) * -1
      toBalance.value = toBalance.value + parseFloat(value)

      let valorCash = Number(value) / 0.75
      let valorLivet = Number(valorCash) * 0.25
      toLivetPay.value = toLivetPay.value + parseFloat(String(valorLivet))

      await fromBalance.save()
      await toBalance.save()
      await toLivetPay.save()

      
      if (hasCashback) {
        if (!saque) {
          //EXTERNAL FUNCTION---------------------------------------------------------
          cashback_sent = await sendCashback(
            transaction[0],
            body.originUser!,
            body.destinationUser!
          )
          //------------------------------------------------------------------------
        } 
         
        if (!cashback_sent) {
          throw new Error('Erro ao distribuir cashback') 
        }
        console.log('depois do cashback')
      }

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

The [transaction advanced usage](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/transactions.html#advanced-usage) is what you need. To work with async await, checkout [this link](https://www.ultimateakash.com/blog-details/IiwzQGAKYAo=/How-to-implement-Transactions-in-Mongoose-&-Node.Js-(Express)).

As described in the linked mongoose documentation, you can call `session.startTransaction()` method to start a transaction, and whenever you wish to abort, call `session.abortTransaction()` to abort the transaction, after all the operations in the transaction are success, call `session.commitTransaction() to commit the transaction`.

Comment: The problem when I use transaction advanced is, it stops two different users of doing a transaction at the same time. Using withTransaction it works.